# Changing size,colors and order in barplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

this is the data_frame I'm working with

```
> Social_Split
           V1
Facebook  220
Instagram 213
Linkedin   73
None        3
Quora      44
Reddit    116
Signal     10
Snapchat  104
TikTok     88
Twitter   129
```

You can reproduce it using this code:

```
Social_Split <- structure(list(V1 = 
c(220L, 213L, 73L, 3L, 44L, 116L, 10L, 104L,88L, 129L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("Facebook","Instagram",
 "Linkedin", "None", "Quora", "Reddit", "Signal",  "Snapchat", "TikTok", "Twitter"))
```

now I plotted this barplot

```
social_colors=c("#9bf6ff","#fdffb6","#bdb2ff","#ffc6ff","#b5e48c"
,"#f07167","#9a8c98","#01497c","#f28482","#84a59d")
par(mar=c(4,5,1,1))
barplot(t(Social_Split),horiz = TRUE,las = 1,col=social_colors)
```

but I have few issues

1. The colors don't change
2. IF POSSIBLE, I'd like to reorder the bins
3. IF POSSIBLE, I'd like to make them thinner

Example of what I want( minus the order ) :
[image]

If using barplot() to manipulate it isn't possible then I don't mind a ggplot() solution as long as I get the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `ggplot2`:

1. Rownames to first column with `tibble::rownames_to_column`
2. `fct_reorder` from `forcats`package to order your data
3. plot with `ggplot`, change `width` as preferred etc....

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

social_colors=c("#9bf6ff","#fdffb6","#bdb2ff","#ffc6ff","#b5e48c"
                ,"#f07167","#9a8c98","#01497c","#f28482","#84a59d")

df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(Social_Split, "Names") %>% 
  mutate(Names = fct_reorder(Names, V1)) 

ggplot(df, aes(x=Names,y=V1, fill = social_colors)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.3)+
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(title = "Number of users per Social Media") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: How can I add a title to this using ggplot("Number of users per Social Media") without adding the legends on the sides that get filled with the social_colors vector?

Comment: Please see my edit. `ggtitle("Number of users per Social Media")`

Comment: that's what I did, the problem is that I don't want to have the social_colors vector on the side displaying the colors. It would better if I remove that or change it to the Soial media

Comment: Ok. See my edit: `labs(title = "Number of users per Social Media") +`

Answer (score 1):

With the base R boxplot function, you can achieve it with some small tweaks.  below changes it will sort the data, with the colours you specified :

```
Social_Split <- structure(list(V1 = c(220L, 213L, 73L, 3L, 44L, 116L, 10L, 104L,88L, 129L)), class = "data.frame", 
                          row.names = c("Facebook","Instagram","Linkedin", "None", "Quora", "Reddit", "Signal",  "Snapchat", "TikTok", "Twitter"))
class(Social_Split)
str(Social_Split)

Social_Split <- Social_Split[order(Social_Split$V1),,drop=FALSE]

par(mar=c(4,5,1,1))
barplot(sort(t(Social_Split)),horiz = TRUE, las = 1, col=social_colors, names.arg = row.names(Social_Split), main = "Number of users per Social Media")
```

The final result will look like this

[image]